# css Suggestion for 3 columns

Tags: css

I'm looking to create a header like:

```
<div id="header>
 <span class="left></span>
 <span class="center"></span>
 <span class="right></span>
</div>
```

So have a header that's all inline. the left to all the way to the left, the right is all the way to the right, and the center is in the center of the header.

The challenge is #header is fluid. Any CSS suggestions. right now the best way I can think to get this done is with a table with 3 rows.

Thanks

Comment: when you say "#header is fluid" do you mean the width? and are you expecting the 3 columns to expand and contract if the width of the header changes?

Comment: correct, the #header is fluid in width... I don't want the 3 columns to expand they can be of fixed width. But I need them to stay aligned. The tricky issue in the .center, I need that to always be center aligned.

Comment: If I understand correctly I think my solution below is what you are after.  you can of course mess around with the css to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/z7k3J/

If you adjust the spacer bar in the middle of the page, you will see that all of your "columns" stay appropriately aligned.

The key is that all of the columns' widths add up to 100% and you float them **all** to the left (or right, it doesn't really matter).  When your widths are percentage-based, they will adjust appropriately as the parent changes size.

If you only care about the text being right/center/left (and not images, etc), you could also make all of the columns 100% width and absolutely positioned, and then just use text-alignment:

http://jsfiddle.net/h7qB8/

Comment: That's pretty good, but now the is at different verticals, the line-height is off.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that floating the left and right spans won't work for you?

Comment: Floating the left and right works fine, but what about the center item? That's what has been confused.

Comment: You could apply "text-align: center" to the center span. Then, anything in it will be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Can you re-order the HTML to be left/right/center (or right/left/center)? If so, [float the columns and use margins or borders on the center](http://phrogz.net/CSS/columns3.html) to hold it off the side bars.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good start:

```
<div id="header" style="position:relative;width:100%;">
 <div class="left" style="position:relative;width:200px;float:left;"></div>
 <div class="center" style="position:relative;float:left;text-align:center;"></div>
 <div class="right" style="position:relative;width:100px;float:right;"></div>
</div>
```

This will center everything in the middle div and keep the other 2 divs to the side. Make sure the element containing the header div is set to position:relative;width:100%; as well.

Comment: Why all of the arbitrary widths in the column elements?

Comment: Just examples, those can be anything, but the left and right divs should have explicit widths.

Comment: The problem is you are floating 2 elements left and 1 element right.  That means that your center span will always be smashed to the left against your left element.

Comment: not sure if the above ensures that the center div is always aligned to the center of his fluid div (header).  Your solution will only keep the left and center div aligned to the left, and when the header expands only the right div will move with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use display: inline-block on the inner elements, on the outer container do a text align center, and then on .left float: left; .right float: right. This would allow you to set a width on the spans, but keep them evenly spaced from the center. See:

```
#header {
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center; 
}

.left, .center, .right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.center {
     text-align: center;

}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

You don't mention it in your question but have it in your tag - if you're able to use CSS3 then the possibilities open up more. You can use the flex box layout: http://www.the-haystack.com/2010/01/23/css3-flexbox-part-1/ or css3 columns: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS3_Columns